# How to work with temporary tables in CakePHP2.x

Tags: model, cakephp-2.1, temp-tables

i read a lot of other postings about my problem, but i don't know how to solve it:

i read 2 tables and want to combine them in one temporary table.

i tried, like other users with following code:

```
    $tmpModel = 'ListTransactions';
    $tmpTable = 'list_transactions';

    $this->ListTransactions->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `".$tmpTable ."`
    (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `sum` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
    `date` datetime NOT NULL,
    `class` enum('Level1','Level2','Level3','Out') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Out',
    `program_id` int(11) NULL,
    `program_title` varchar(150) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )"
    );
    App::import('Model', $tmpModel);
    $this->loadModel($tmpModel);
```

table creation returns true, so i think table was created.
but when i want to save some data, i get a "table doesn't exists"-error.

```
    foreach ($payments as $payment) {
        $this->ListTransactions->create();
        $this->ListTransactions->set(array(
            'id' => $payment['Payments']['id'],
            'sum' => $payment['Payments']['sum'],
            'date' => $payment['Payments']['check_date'],
            'class' => 'Out',
            'user_id' => $UserId
        ));
        $this->ListTransactions->save();
    }
     Error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'list_transactions' doesn't exist

    SQL Query: SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `list_transactions` AS `ListTransactions` WHERE `ListTransactions`.`id` = '1'
```

please help :(

greetings
M.

Comment: ah, i had a problems with single-quotes. but saving data still not working: $this->ListTransactions->save() returns false.

Comment: Have you tried to base it purely on queryes? 
I could be that Cake'ORM couldn't handle query creation for all tasks.

Comment: Were you able to achieve this? Please let us know if you did.